# Build error with xsens_node autoware

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
unfortunately I am new to most aspects of autoware. I tried to follow the Autoware.Auto installation.
The problem I have occured during my ade$ colcon build attempt. Here comes an extract of what kind of output was generated: https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/issues/582
I have no idea how to approach this error message and I would be very happy about any guidance.
If you need any further information, just tell me.
Kind regards, Lennart

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359476/build-error-with-xsens_node-autoware/) by [LennartL](https://answers.ros.org/users/57733/lennartl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We had to make a change to reflect changes to a new version of the `transport_drivers` repository (`udp_driver` and `serial_driver`) being released to the build farm. This was fixed with [this commit](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/commit/50a6256fd107b8f13d8214652aae52a1c71573a4) several months ago. Please pull the latest copy of the code with `git pull` and this should be resolved.

Additionally, you likely have old versions of the `ade` docker images. Please follow the [General Troubleshooting Steps](https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/installation.html#autotoc_md93) to update everything.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LennartL](https://answers.ros.org/users/57733/lennartl/) on 2020-08-18**:
This helped, thank you very much.